# Unzip 7zip to certain directory

Tags: 7-zip

I'm using this command line:

```
7z e d:\dev\projects\dbs\test\osc.data.db d:\dev\projects\dbs\test\osc.data.7z
```

I think the first parameter should be the output, and the 2nd paramater should be the input.

However, I switched them already, and none of my solutions would work.

Does anybody spot any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Use the -o switch:

```
7z e d:\dev\projects\dbs\test\osc.data.7z -od:\dev\projects\dbs\test\
```